# Unique list elements in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I have two Tcl lists of equal length, `u` and `v`. Many of the entries in `u` are known to be identical. For every unique entry in `u`, I would like to average over the corresponding entries in `v`. So, if my lists are `{1 2 1 2}` and `{1 2 3 4}`, the output should be `{1 2}` (only the unique entries in `u`), and `{2 3}`, where 2 comes from `(1+3)/2`, and 3 comes from `(2+4)/2`.

I have tried the following:

```
set unique [lsort -unique $u]
foreach i $unique {
  set ave 0; set N 0
  foreach j $u k $v {
    if {$i == $j} {set ave [expr {$ave+$k}]}
  }
  lappend w [expr {$ave/$N}]
}
```

This works, but it is far too slow for larger lists. Does anyone know a more efficient way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a dictionary to accumulate values in groups by unique keys. This would do pretty much the entire process for me (together with a bit of post-processing to get the averages).

```
foreach a $u b $v {
    dict lappend collector $a $b
}
set uniques [dict keys $collector]
set averages [lmap items [dict values $collector] {
    expr { [tcl::mathop::+ {*}$items] / double([llength $items]) }
}
```

The averages are naturally floating point values.